# HttpClient: how to send parameters and retreive answer

Tags: c#, http

I need to send a request to a license server.
I tried it using FireFox like this:

```
http://my.server.com/sub/?aaa=5d1606&bbb=ccc&key=5d160
```

and that works. I get the correct response.
Now I do it in C#:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var SKey = "blabla";
    var LKey = "bloblo";
    string param = String.Format($"?aaa={SKey}&bbb=ccc&key={LKey}");
    Debug.WriteLine(param);
    var content = new StringContent(param);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://my.server.com/sub/", content);
    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
}
```

That don't work: the responseString is null.
Any suggestions/solutions/remarks?
I'd be grateful.

Comment: If it works in FireFox, chances are it is a GET and you need to call GetAsync instead of PostAsync. One more thing, you are sending the parameters as content when sending them just as part of the URL may be expected.

Comment: i guess you misinterpreted HTTPGET and HTTPPOST.
you might need to try GETAsync, or serialise object for post

Comment: Swap GetAsync for PostAsync and send one long string instead of the "content" does not work either. Still get a null. param gets printed correctly, responseString is blank (string.Empty or null)

Comment: Does the site check any browser cookies? I would also recommend using a dictionary for the parameters, since then the formatting will be done for you: https://pastebin.com/3dwA2aKp

Comment: cookies are not checked by the server (which is mine at my hoster). thnx for pastebin. But that does not work either. I started with that but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your content is not being serialized to be passed in the POST request like you are doing.

Either setup your server to recieve a JSON body content and use a JSON seralizer to pass the content to the service, or append the paramters to the url and just pass that to your request.

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://my.server.com/sub/" + param);
```